# How do I configure the yaml pipeline in azure devops in a way that would only deploy the recent changes, rather than the whole build?

Tags: azure, yaml, devops, configure, azure-pipelines-yaml

How do I configure the yaml pipeline in azure devops in a way that would only deploy the recent changes, rather than the whole build?

I tried looking up 'ref' and other variables that are used but no luck.

Edit: For example, I would like run the pipeline based off the latest commit as seen in the image. Is there a way to configure a variable that will tell the yaml file "every time you run this pipeline, start from the latest commit". The image shows the manual way, is there a way to automate this process?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EArtB.png)

Comment: It depends how your pipeline is setup and what exactly you mean by _recent changes_. Please add more context and details to your question.

Comment: Hey @Sibtain thanks for your comment. An example situation is that instead of having the pipeline to build and deploy the whole build every time it runs, it would only deploy the latest commit. Currently our project is premature but in the long run will definitely get more sophisticated. We want to ensure that everytime the pipeline runs it would only run what is new so that it would be efficient and not time consuming. I've had a look at 'incremental builds' and 'caching' but don't think there's enough resources to show how it's done. Thanks again.

Comment: Again, you need to be more specific and come up with a POC pipeline and show how everything is being build and deployed. Once you have a working pipeline, after that it would be possible to tell how that can be done.

Comment: @Sibtain, just made an edit. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The question is *what is the smallest unit of deployment in your project?*.

If you have single monolith application, the pipeline *should* only deploy the whole app.

If you have multiple apps/services, then you could have one pipeline per one app/service. You specify trigger, and the pipelines can be independent of each other (just like the source code and the deployed services).

Of course there are many ways to do this depending on the app and overall complexity.